# How to determine a reason of slow WiFi in my local network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

In local network of company I have nodes connected over cable and over Wifi. Local network is run with Netis router (installed right under the ceiling). Interestingly but nodes connected by cable run OK, but nodes connected by WiFi have poor connection. For example, node 192.168.0.40 is connected by WiFi and 192.168.0.34 is connected by cable, both are in local network:

```
ping 192.168.0.40

Pinging 192.168.0.40 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=131ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.40: bytes=32 time=130ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.40:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 31ms, Maximum = 131ms, Average = 88ms

ping 192.168.0.34

Pinging 192.168.0.34 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.34: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.34: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.34: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.34: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.34:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 1ms
```

I have used WireShark and I don't see any IP conflicts which may be hindering network.

How do I dispatch the reason of poor wifi connection?

---

**Edit... 04.03.2019** This problem still persists (Although it was fine month ago). Some side notes:

- This is a metal processing factory with some really powerful electrical engines.
- Also workers do use wifi connection extensively (this is approved by engineer)
- Company operates two routers : One is Netis WF2419 router (192.168.0.1) with DHCP enabled (192.168.0.3 - 192.168.0.254), another is TPLink WR841N router (192.168.0.3) with DHCP disabled and connected to LAN port of Netis router. Protection for 192.168.0.1 is WPA/WPA2-PSK and encryption is TKIP&AES. Protection for 192.168.0.2 is WPA/WPA2 Personal, version WPA2-PSK and encryption is set to Automatic.
- I have came 15 minutes before the start of working day, and it was working nice, but then workers started to arrive, bringing their phones with them and launching machinery. And things have gone wrong...
- Channels are not overlapped (I am using inssider with some wifi adapter. (Wireshark does not work with wifi) ):

[image: Signal channels levels of routers.]

*If this is a problem with machine, leaking strong magnetic field - I cannot do a thing. And there is no way to prove such assumption to engineer.*

**If this is a problem with user's phone, how do I find out which one is causing trouble (and block its MAC on router) without banning "innocent" users?**

Comment: How many people do connect to each router? Remember the models you're using are home/small office so optimized for low number of users (5 contemporary users each). I suggest you to enable QoS and set a fairy strict, policy (max 2 megabit per IP) so 'heavy users' will be pushed to go wired, eventually giving more bandwidth, if needed, only to those that really need mobility.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your goal this could be hard. The reason for slowness could be any one or more of the following:

- Bad radio / badly designed antenna
- Congestion from other networks on same/overlapping frequencies
- Interference from other non-wifi devices (eg microwaves, baby monitors, electric motors)
- Distance from base station
- Using old standards
- Bad firmware.
- Other WIFI users

None of these will be apparent using wireshark, but making changes to mitigate each of the above and looking at the SNR values reported by your device can help.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - thank you, and yes, it was my phone auto-correct misbehaving.

Comment: Okay, so how do I dispatch this?

Comment: You diagnose which of the above elements are in play and mitigate/fix each one. How yoi do this depends on what available resources you have and the environment.  As I have an android phone, I might start by downloading the WIFI analyser app and doing a site survey to see how many outside APs there are, there..signal strengths and.frequencies, and also how your signal behaves relative to the distance from your router. I'd then build a plan to replace/suplement/reconfigure things as makes sense from my findings.

Comment: What model is your router? Id like to look at its specs and beam formation.

Comment: Added this info to original post. Thanks for attention

Comment: I dont know about thebrand, but you will likely benefit by replacing the netis router with something newer. That router looks entry level (US$26  does not buy much). It is also N standard at 300 megabits. Ugrading to an AC router will do a few things to help generally but even more so when talking with other AC  devices - specifically (1) faster comms provides better use of bandwidth - 4-8 times as much bandwidth in fact, (2) Multiple antennas provide better "corridors" and noise cancellation which can help with motors which no doubt are causing interference.

Comment: Also, consider adding more access points to increase the signal to noise ratio. A lot if people swear by Ubiquity gear which is fafordable prosumer gear, and often deployed in more complex environments.

Comment: It may also make sense to look fir gear whichbcan operate in the 5gig band as well, again providing more bandwidth, but also having a useful (in this case) property of not penetrating walls, which could mean less interference from heavy machinery.

Comment: Like your Netis router your WR841N is fairly old and should be replaced with domething that is dual band and AC.